# Select Flex tab with data attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs, flexbox

Here is an approach to create a tab component using css flex property.
I want to toggle tab and its contain with ‘data-title’ and ‘data-content’.
Toggle when data-title = data-content.
How I fill dynamic data to tab title and tab content.

**Please suggest how I can do it.**

Demo: URL: http://codepen.io/JEETPAL/pen/JKLyRA?editors=0010

Here is the HTML

```
    <dl class="tabs">
        <dt class="active" data-title="latest_news">LATEST NEWS</dt>
        <dd data-content="latest_news">
          <h3>Elephants stranded in canal, rescued after hour long operation
</h3>
          <p>Forest officials rescued a herd of seven elephants, including two calves, after they were stranded in a canal for close to an hour in West Bengal's Jalpaiguri city.</p>
        </dd>
<dt data-title="entertainment">ENTERTAINMENT</dt>
        <dd data-content="entertainment">
          <h3>Tiger Shroff nails 'A Flying Jatt' title track</h3>
          <p>The title track of 'A Flying Jatt' seems to be a powerful answer to Tiger Shroff's critics who wrote off the newcomer. The catchy number is peppy, funny and every bit entertaining.
Featuring cute dancers dressed as mini Flying Jatts in blue, and several kids handpicked by director Remo D'souza himself for their dancing prowess including Flying Jatt's little 'possessive girlfriend,' the title song hints that the superhero flick can be an out and out laugh riot.</p>
        </dd>
….
</dl>
```

Comment: Would it be okay if I help you using javascript?

Comment: try only. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOxJwX

Comment: @Hayley Kiara,
Yes you can use JavaScript  or jquery

Comment: @Hayley Kiara, How can I use dynamic data, using Jason, please guide

Comment: Jason? You mean json, right?

Comment: @Hayley Kiara, Yes it json

Comment: You need to create an object and put the details in array. So that you can loop through it.

Comment: @Hayley Kiara, please guide how can i do it

Comment: I already guide you. Just follow my instruction. Create an json object and put the data in array. Assign key in value. And just iterate it using for loop and put some functions into it. You need innerHTML, setAttribute. Note: you can set class in attribute. You don't need to use classList.

Comment: @Hayley Kiara, Thanks

Comment: Try it first. If you don't get it. I can help you. I have no problem helping people.